# Proxy authentication error - python

Tags: python, authentication, proxy, urllib2, python-2.6

Hi I have written a few simple lines of code. But I seem to be getting a Authentication error. Can anyone please suggest , what credentials are being looked for python here ?

Code:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
html = response.read()
```

Error

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required
```

PS: I do not have acces to IE -->Advanced settings or `regedit`

As advised I've modified the code :

```
import urllib2
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':r'http://usename:psw@IP:port'})
auth = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, auth, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
html = response.read()
```

Also I have created two environment variables :

```
HTTP_PROXY = http://username:password@proxyserver.domain.com
HTTPS_PROXY = https://username:password@proxyserver.domain.com
```

But still getting the error .

`urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proxy Authentication error in Urllib2 (Python 2.7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520790/proxy-authentication-error-in-urllib2-python-2-7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to work-around your problem. You may want to try defining an environment variables with the names `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` with each set to you proxy URL. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520790/proxy-authentication-error-in-urllib2-python-2-7) link for more details.

Alternatively, you may want to explicitly define a **ProxyHandler** to work with urllib2 while handling requests through the proxy. The link is already present within the comment to your query; however I am including it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763028/python-3-urllib-http-error-407-proxy-authentication-required) for the sake of completeness.

Hope this helps

Comment: where do i get case1: username/password/proxyserver.domain.com

Comment: You either set the _proxy variables or you use the ProxyHandler. I am not aware what happens if you do both

Comment: Didn't resolve the issue , but insights were helpful . Thanks.

Comment: Please try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327654/proxy-authentication-error-python/30626865#30626865

Answer (score 1):

If your OS is **windows and behind ISA proxy**, urllib2 does not use any information about proxy; instead "Firewall Client for ISA server" automatically authenticates the user. That means we don't need to set `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` system environment variables. Keep it empty in `ProxyHandler` as following:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

u = urllib2.urlopen('your-url-goes-here')
data = u.read()
```

Answer (score -1):

The error code and message seem that the username and password failed to pass the authentications of proxy servers.

The following code:

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'usename:psw@IP:port'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
html = response.read()
```

should also works if the authentication is passed.